# Distinguising two error terms in rounding error

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point

Considering two non-floating-point numbers $x$ and $y$, we write their floating point representation as $\operatorname{fl}(x)$ and $\operatorname{fl}(y)$ respectively. By $\circ$, we denote an arithmetic operation.

Now, in my text a distinction is made between an error caused in the *data* and a second one caused by *converting the result of an exact calculation to floating point form*. This is illustrated by using the triangle inequality, where these two errors are represented by the first and second term on the right hand side, respectively:

> $$
> \big|\ x\circ y - \operatorname{fl} \big( \operatorname{fl}(x) \circ \operatorname{fl}(y) \big) \big|
> \leq \big|\ x \circ y - \operatorname{fl}(x) \circ \operatorname{fl}(y) \big| + \big| \ \operatorname{fl}(x) \circ \operatorname{fl}(y) -\operatorname{fl}\big( \operatorname{fl} \big( \operatorname{fl}(x) \circ \operatorname{fl}(y) \big) \big|
> $$

I want to understand what is meant by the statement $\big| \ x \circ y - \operatorname{fl}(x) \circ \operatorname{fl}(y) \big| $ is caused by *an error in the data*.

**Supplement.**

The application of the triangle inequality can be seen by denoting $a := x \circ y$, $\ b := \operatorname{fl}(x) \circ \operatorname{fl}(y)$ and $\ c := \operatorname{fl}(b)$:

$$
|a-c| = |(a-b)+(b-c)| \leq |a-c| + |b-c| \ .
$$

Text: Numerical Methods for Ordinary Differential Equations, second edition (Vuik,2016), page 4; 1.4 rounding errors.

Comment: I can't tell where you are stuck, it seems unambiguous and straightforward. E.g. with two significant digits, $x=1.66, y=1.37$, thus $fl(x)=1.7, fl(y)=1.4$. Then $x \times y =  2.2742$, $fl(x) \times fl(y) = 2.38$, $fl(fl(x) \times fl(y)) = 2.4$.

Comment: @njuffa I can do the computations, obviously. It is about the phrasing of *error in the data*.

Comment: I don't see a clearly defined question in the above, defined as a sentence that ends in a question mark. What specifically is the question you want answered?

Comment: @njuffa I want to pinpoint where the two seperate error terms come from. The triangle equality validates the equation. But somehow, my text attributes a specific origin for the first term by using the phrasing *error in the data*. Hence, there is some deeper reason why this term appears, other than the triangle equality. I want to understand what is meant by *error in the data*. I really don't have a clue, and this bothers me. :)

Comment: I would suggest updating the above accordingly.  I understand "error in the data" to refer to $x \ne fl(x)$, e.g. $\pi \ne fl(\pi) = 3.1415926$.

Answer (score 0):

A more elaborate phrasing of the text's `error in the data` can be given by: *an error caused by the (finite) representation of the data $\operatorname{fl}(x)$ and $\operatorname{fl}(y)$*.

Comment: This is not really an answer to your own question? Rather you are adding information. It is in you own interest to edit your original question instead.

Comment: @CarlChristian I agree; just made the edit.